# Remove SVG/XML child element based on value

Tags: xml, vba, svg

I have an SVG file, my problem is to remove text element if the value is not a integer using VBA. Did a search and found this article but couldn't get it to work for me [Remove a parent node and all children based on text value in child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316813/remove-a-parent-node-and-all-children-based-on-text-value-in-child)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg>
  <image height="1980" width="1530" x="0" xlink:href="file.png" y="0"/>
  <g stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1">
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="15"   x="645" y="532">A</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="19"   x="1391" y="603">2</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="15"   x="261" y="689">A</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="15"   x="1008" y="749">4</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="14"   x="1009" y="768">eD</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="16"   x="117" y="765">A</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="14"   x="199" y="1115">Q</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="19"   x="1393" y="1113">3</text>
    <text>DRA</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="19"   x="1131" y="1189">(?YPI PL?I CEG)</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="19"   x="340" y="1310">B</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="19"   x="1223" y="1310">6</text>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="18"   x="1222" y="1364">7</text>

    <text fill="#000000" font-family="Arial" font-size="19"   x="755" y="1484">(?YAL I6 PL)</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Code

```
Public Sub xml()


Set XMLDoc = _
CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLDoc.Async = "False"
XMLDoc.Load ("C:\Users\1\g2.xml")

strVulid = "eD"
XPath = "svg/g[/text = '" & strVulid & "']"

For Each n In XMLDoc.SelectNodes(XPath)
    n.ParentNode.RemoveChild (n)
Next

XMLDoc.Save "C:\Users\1\sample.xml"
MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: added code. please check

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Nothing. the sample.xml reproduces the source as is.

Answer (score 0):

The following use xml linq to remove the elements from the XDocument.  The code parse all the attributes just incase you need the extra data

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim value As Integer
        Dim fonts As List(Of Font) = doc.Descendants("text").Select(Function(x) New Font() With { _
                                                                         .fill = CType(x.Attribute("fill"), String),
                                                                         .fontFamily = CType(x.Attribute("font-family"), String),
                                                                         .size = CType(x.Attribute("font-size"), Integer?),
                                                                         .x = CType(x.Attribute("x"), Integer?),
                                                                         .y = CType(x.Attribute("y"), Integer?),
                                                                         .value = CType(x, String),
                                                                         .element = x
                                                                     }).ToList()

        For i = fonts.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Not Integer.TryParse(fonts(i).value, value) Then
                fonts(i).element.Remove()
            End If
        Next i

    End Sub

End Module
Public Class Font
    Public element As XElement
    Public fill As String
    Public fontFamily As String
    Public size As Integer?
    Public x As Integer?
    Public y As Integer?
    Public value As String


End Class
```